# Is it okay to say 'fraud oneself to the office'?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Multiple times, I came across structures like '[verb] oneself to/into/through [something]' that mean "by doing [verb] achieve/pass etc. [something]". Is my expression 'fraud oneself to the office' grammatical and, not less importantly, idiomatical? If not, how can I fix it (but, if possible, still employing the described structure)? What I mean is, for example, by rigging an election, win the presidential post.

Comment: FYI, you want to know if your phrase is _idiomatic_, not _idiomatical_

Comment: @Kevin FYI, https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/idiomatical

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idiomatic%2C+idiomatical&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidiomatic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiomatical%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**
"Fraud oneself to the office" is neither grammatically correct nor idiomatic.

First, "fraud" is a noun, not a verb.

Second, "to the office" sounds like you are going to work.  "Into office" is used when referring to obtaining a government position.

An idiomatic way to say this would be "get into office by fraud"

Comment: How about 'cheat oneself into office'? And why can't I use the definite article if I mean one specific office (for example, the presidential office)?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev If you were to use "into the Presidential office" would be fine,  but "the office" by itself is a phrase meaning your place of work, as in "I had to go into the office on Saturday because the servers crashed".  And yes, "cheat yourself into office" or "cheat yourself into the Oval Office" would be fine. But I think "cheat your way" would be more common

Comment: Can you, in grammatical terms, explain why 'the' would be out of place?

Comment: @Sergey, using *the* here isn't ungrammatical, but it changes the meaning. What's ungrammatical is using *fraud* as if it were a verb.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev it's not ungrammatical, it just is already part of a set idiom. Unless you were using it in context and which specific office you were talking about had already been established. "You can't say that to me, I'm the one sitting in the Governor's Office" "Yeah, but you cheated your way into the office"

Comment: @Kevin Like in this sentence: 'Manafort helped Yanukovych become the president of Ukraine in 2010 after his first foiled attempt to cheat his way into THE office in 2004'?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Yes, exactly like that